# How to compress medium text (json actually) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hey I am functioning as SRE in my company.
We have a table contains  big json files.
Our column type is medium text, and the table is really used frequently.
Thousands of select and insert every minute.
This situation leading us for each row selected 1 sec +-.

```
What is the best way to decrease the time? (AVG row size = 9704, from index side we are good same queries with select count(*) taking short time)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't do much with that other than upgrading your hardware. A thing you could do instead is to migrate to `MongoDB`. Basically, you could save the JSON into a `collection` and then store the `id` of the document into the column that now holds the JSON, just like a `Foreign Key`